# How to implement momentum-based stochastic gradient descent (SGD)

Tags: python, momentum

I am using the python code network3.py (http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap6.html) for developing convolutional neural networks. Now I want to modify the code a little bit by adding a momentum learning rule as follows:

```
velocity = momentum_constant * velocity - learning_rate * gradient
params = params + velocity
```

Is there anyone knowing how to do that? In particular, how to set up or initialize the velocity? I post the codes for SGD below:

```
def __init__(self, layers, mini_batch_size):
    """Takes a list of `layers`, describing the network architecture, and
    a value for the `mini_batch_size` to be used during training
    by stochastic gradient descent.

    """
    self.layers = layers
    self.mini_batch_size = mini_batch_size
    self.params = [param for layer in self.layers for param in layer.params]
    self.x = T.matrix("x")
    self.y = T.ivector("y")
    init_layer = self.layers[0]
    init_layer.set_inpt(self.x, self.x, self.mini_batch_size)
    for j in xrange(1, len(self.layers)):
        prev_layer, layer  = self.layers[j-1], self.layers[j]
        layer.set_inpt(
            prev_layer.output, prev_layer.output_dropout, self.mini_batch_size)
    self.output = self.layers[-1].output
    self.output_dropout = self.layers[-1].output_dropout


def SGD(self, training_data, epochs, mini_batch_size, eta,
        validation_data, test_data, lmbda=0.0):
    """Train the network using mini-batch stochastic gradient descent."""
    training_x, training_y = training_data
    validation_x, validation_y = validation_data
    test_x, test_y = test_data

    # compute number of minibatches for training, validation and testing
    num_training_batches = size(training_data)/mini_batch_size
    num_validation_batches = size(validation_data)/mini_batch_size
    num_test_batches = size(test_data)/mini_batch_size

    # define the (regularized) cost function, symbolic gradients, and updates
    l2_norm_squared = sum([(layer.w**2).sum() for layer in self.layers])
    cost = self.layers[-1].cost(self)+\
           0.5*lmbda*l2_norm_squared/num_training_batches
    grads = T.grad(cost, self.params)
    updates = [(param, param-eta*grad)
               for param, grad in zip(self.params, grads)]

    # define functions to train a mini-batch, and to compute the
    # accuracy in validation and test mini-batches.
    i = T.lscalar() # mini-batch index
    train_mb = theano.function(
        [i], cost, updates=updates,
        givens={
            self.x:
            training_x[i*self.mini_batch_size: (i+1)*self.mini_batch_size],
            self.y:
            training_y[i*self.mini_batch_size: (i+1)*self.mini_batch_size]
        })
    validate_mb_accuracy = theano.function(
        [i], self.layers[-1].accuracy(self.y),
        givens={
            self.x:
            validation_x[i*self.mini_batch_size: (i+1)*self.mini_batch_size],
            self.y:
            validation_y[i*self.mini_batch_size: (i+1)*self.mini_batch_size]
        })
    test_mb_accuracy = theano.function(
        [i], self.layers[-1].accuracy(self.y),
        givens={
            self.x:
            test_x[i*self.mini_batch_size: (i+1)*self.mini_batch_size],
            self.y:
            test_y[i*self.mini_batch_size: (i+1)*self.mini_batch_size]
        })
    self.test_mb_predictions = theano.function(
        [i], self.layers[-1].y_out,
        givens={
            self.x:
            test_x[i*self.mini_batch_size: (i+1)*self.mini_batch_size]
        })
    # Do the actual training
    best_validation_accuracy = 0.0
    for epoch in xrange(epochs):
        for minibatch_index in xrange(num_training_batches):
            iteration = num_training_batches*epoch+minibatch_index
            if iteration % 1000 == 0:
                print("Training mini-batch number {0}".format(iteration))
            cost_ij = train_mb(minibatch_index)
            if (iteration+1) % num_training_batches == 0:
                validation_accuracy = np.mean(
                    [validate_mb_accuracy(j) for j in xrange(num_validation_batches)])
                print("Epoch {0}: validation accuracy {1:.2%}".format(
                    epoch, validation_accuracy))
                if validation_accuracy >= best_validation_accuracy:
                    print("This is the best validation accuracy to date.")
                    best_validation_accuracy = validation_accuracy
                    best_iteration = iteration
                    if test_data:
                        test_accuracy = np.mean(
                            [test_mb_accuracy(j) for j in xrange(num_test_batches)])
                        print('The corresponding test accuracy is {0:.2%}'.format(
                            test_accuracy))
```

Answer (score 6):

I have only ever coded up SDG from scratch (not using theano), but judging from your code you need to

1) initiate the `velocities` with a bunch of zeros (one per gradient),

2) include the velocity in your updates; something like

```
updates = [(param, param-eta*grad +momentum_constant*vel)
           for param, grad, vel in zip(self.params, grads, velocities)]
```

3) amend your training function to return the gradients on each iteration so that you can update the `velocities`.

Comment: Can you write up the codes for 1) and 3) in your answer. I am just a beginner to Python.  Is the theano.function the training function you mention?  Thanks！！

Comment: Your training function is a theano function but not all theano functions are training functions. E.g., just in the code you posted there are 3 different instances. This might sound harsh but you if you don't know how to initiate an array with zeros (point 1) then you should a) forget about machine learning for a while, and b) do some tutorials for scientific programming in numpy. The same goes for theano. Everything else will be black magic (for you).

Comment: This is my class assignment. I have to try hard to keep going！